# Can anyone explain about the tic tac toe winning condition?

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

i am a beginner in java android development and i have created a tic tac toe game. i have finished the code for the game . but i am confused about the winning condition of the game as i am just learning from an instructor online.
this is the specific code that i'm clueless about the game

```
//winning condition
//for(int [] winningPosition : winningPositions){
        if(gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2)
```

this is the code. (I did not posted the entire code as i just want to show the relevant code to help you understand what i'm trying to ask)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//0 = yellow , 1 = red;
int activePlayer = 0;
boolean gameIsActive = true;
//2 mean unplayed
int [] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
int [][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};

public void dropIn (View view) {

    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;


    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());
    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {

        gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;


        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);
        if (activePlayer == 0) {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            activePlayer = 1;
        } else {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            activePlayer = 0;
        }

        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360).setDuration(300);
        for(int []winningPosition : winningPositions){

            if(gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2)
                            {
                                //Someone has won!
                                gameIsActive = false;
                                String winner = "Red";
                                if(gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0){

                                 winner = "Yellow";
                            }
                                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
                                TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                                winnerMessage.setText( winner +" has won!");
                                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




            } else {

                boolean gameIsOver = true;
                for(int counterState : gameState){

                    if(counterState == 2) gameIsOver = false;


                }
                if(gameIsOver){

                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
                    TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                    winnerMessage.setText( "It's a draw!");
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What is it that you're clueless about?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: He is asking for the TicTacToe rules... This isn't a programmation question.

Comment: are you asking for bug fixes in your code or are you asking for someone to explain the code for you?

Comment: im asking how does the wining condition actually work?

Answer (score 1):

`winningPositions` holds all possible field-combinations that you can hold to win the game (the three rows, the three columns and the two diagonals). Your code iterates over these `winningPositions` and for each checks whether all three fields are held by the same person and that this person is not no-one (`//2 mean unplayed`).

Answer (score 0):

a winner in this game should match 3 symbol (cross or circle) in a row in Vertical, Diagonal or horizontal line. Please refer attached images in which player playing with circle is winner in every image.[image: Vertical match]

[[image: Diagonal match match[2]][image: Horizontal]

Answer (score 0):

Basically what it does is this:
For every winning state (which is every possible line of three boxes), it wants to know if they have the same state (X, O or void), and if they are not void (which is what I suppose the number 2 means).